# How to define placeholder text in Select2 JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I can never define placeholder text in Select2 JQuery Plugin. I tried the code

```
$("#first").select2({
    placeholder: {id: "", text: "Choose an option…"}
});
```

but it doesn't work for me. My code is [here](http://jsbin.com/ipimon/2/edit)

And, how to rectangle for search be [rounded](http://postimg.org/image/3m2s7ra43/), what is the version of Select2?

Answer (score 7):

You have to add an empty option to the beginning of your select element:

```
<select name="first" id="first"> 
    <option></option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then simply add a placeholder like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").select2({
        placeholder: "Your placeholder",
        allowClear: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The placeholder option should be a string as specified in the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). That being said, your code should be just:

```
$("#first").select2({
    placeholder: "Choose an option…"
});
```

For the search input to be rounded: do it yourself via CSS. Current version (v3.4.0) doesn't have this "feature" yet.

Comment: I'm not surprised to see that an untested code is not working properly (or it's not well documented). If you want, give a try at my very own [bselect](http://gustavohenke.github.io/bselect/). It doesn't have all those features yet, but I'm on my way.